# htmlspecialchars function with accents

Tags: php

When I insert an accented letter as "è à ù" the function does not work, it does not return anything, why?

```
$test = "è ò ù";
echo htmlspecialchars($test, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: https://eval.in/573705

Comment: don't work on my localhost, why?

Comment: for example, because coding of your php file is not utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<?php
$test = "è ò ù";
echo htmlspecialchars($test, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
?>
```